# How to stop Mac from opening a new tab when I click a link

Tags: mac, safari

Let's say I search "pineapple" in Google and click on the first link, it opens that link in a new tab and I find this annoying. I can't seem to fix this and I know that the command key is not stuck. How do I solve this?

Comment: Check the preferences, this can usually be set to new window or new tab.

Answer (score 1):

> Safari > Preferences > Tabs

Uncheck the checkbox called 'When a new tab or window opens, make it active'